# Alterar cor PHP/Html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

estou com o seguinte problema e creio que o JS possa ajudar, mas conheco quase nada de JS.

preciso que o conteudo da tag "td" se for igual a "Montar" fique verde e se for "Aguardar" fique vermelho.

```
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Buscar">
        <table class="table table-dark table-hover" id="table">
            <caption>Operacao</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ativo</th>
                    <th>Sinal</th>
                    <th>Cotação</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $linha['ATIVO'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $linha['Robo PUT'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $linha['Real Time'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Não me parece que javascript seja a melhor opção para efetuar o que pretende. Pode aplicar uma classe (ou inline styling) de acordo com uma condição em php. Em qual das três `td` pretende alterar a cor?

Comment: A linha do meio, onde que deverá ser o sinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente algo como:

```
<td <? if ($linha['Robo PUT'] == 'Montar'): echo "style='color: red;'"; endif; ?>>
   <?= $linha['Robo PUT'] ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Ainda nao deu certo... style="color: red;" > Montar  esse é o resultado na tela.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado. estou aprofundando os estudos em PHP.